# SQL C# stored procedure insert into

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to insert values into a new line in the table tblPositions in my database Aktiendepot. Nothing happens when I run it. The values that are passed to the method should be fine.

aspx.cs

```
protected void StockBuy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Methods CustomMethods = new Methods();
    CustomMethods.BuyStock(sSymbol, sCompany, sExchange, iQuantity, dPrice, sUsername);
}
```

Methods.cs

```
public void BuyStock(string sSymbol, string sCompany, string sExchange, int iQuantity, double dPrice, string sUsername) //Inserts stock information to database
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=admin;" +
                                          "password=1337passwort;server=localhost;" +
                                          "database=Aktiendepot; " +
                                          "connection timeout=30"); //Establishes Connection
        SqlCommand InsertStockInformation = new SqlCommand("StockBuy", con);
        InsertStockInformation.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter quantity = new SqlParameter("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int, 5,iQuantity.ToString());
        quantity.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add(quantity);
        SqlParameter symbol = new SqlParameter("@symbol", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, sSymbol);
        symbol.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add(symbol);
        SqlParameter company = new SqlParameter("@company", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30, sCompany);
        company.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add(company);
        SqlParameter exchange = new SqlParameter("@exchange", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20, sExchange);
        exchange.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add(exchange);
        SqlParameter buymktprice = new SqlParameter("@buymktprice", SqlDbType.Float, 50, dPrice.ToString());
        buymktprice.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add(buymktprice);
        SqlParameter username = new SqlParameter("@username", sUsername);
        username.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add(username);
        con.Open();
        InsertStockInformation.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
}
```

Here is how I created the table

```
create table tblPositions (PosID int NOT NULL identity(1,1), PosQuantity int NOT NULL, PosSymbol varchar(10) NOT NULL, PosCompany varchar(30) NOT NULL, PosExchange varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                       PosBuyMktPrice float NOT NULL, PosBuyDate date NOT NULL, FK_PosUsername varchar(50) NOT NULL foreign key references tblUsers(UserUsername),
                       primary key (PosID));
```

Here is the stored procedure

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StockBuy]
(
@username as varchar(50),
@quantity as int,
@symbol as varchar(50),
@company as varchar(30),
@exchange as varchar(20),
@buymktprice as float
)
AS
INSERT INTO tblPositions (PosQuantity,PosSymbol,PosCompany,PosExchange,PosBuyMktPrice,PosBuyDate,FK_PosUsername) VALUES (@quantity,@symbol,@company,@exchange,@buymktprice,GETDATE(),@username)
```

Comment: What is your `StockBuy` definition?

Comment: Looks fine. Please provide StockBuy SP.

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what's going on line by line?

Comment: @Orlando : have you debug it to check if there are any exceptions?

Comment: In your real code, do you have anything in the `catch` block?

Comment: @JonSkeet no there's nothing

Comment: @Orlando put `@` symbol while adding the parameters and check..sometime it can make issue `new SqlParameter("@quantity", iQuantity);

Comment: just debuged it witch fixed values instead of variables, did work

Comment: Are you sure the connection is made to the Db? You're using both *Trusted_Connection* (odbc) and *User Id/Password*. The former is windows auth and the latter is Sql login.

Comment: @Orlando: Please put *details* of that into the question. It's not at all clear to me exactly what you mean.

Comment: can you try specifying the `SqlDbType` and `Direction` as well?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh what do you mean?

Comment: try adding these properties in sqlparameter.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh like it is now?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh still not inserting anything

Comment: Just found out that the method was never run.... it was fine.
Still thanks to everyone for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
try
     {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=admin;" +
       "password=1337passwort;" +"server=localhost;" +
        "database=Aktiendepot; " +
         "connection timeout=30"); //Establishes Connection
     SqlCommand InsertStockInformation = new SqlCommand("StockBuy", con);
     InsertStockInformation.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add("@quantity",SqlDbType.Int).Value=quantity;
     InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add("@symbol",SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value=sSymbol;
     InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add("@company",SqlDbType.NVarChar,30).Value=sCompany;
     InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add("@exchange",SqlDbType.NVarChar,20).Value=sExchange;
     InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add("@buymktprice",SqlDbType.Float,50).Value=dPrice;
      InsertStockInformation.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value=sUsername;

con.Open();
 InsertStockInformation.ExecuteNonQuery();


con.Close();
 }
 catch(SqlException ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

}
```

Comment: @Orlando still the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Keep **breakpoints** and check the execution flow of your codes.

```
    catch(SqlException ex)
    {
        //Error
    }
```

Above is your `catch` block where in which there is not capturing of error.Maybe the error produced is getting **suppressed** in the `catch` block.

[image]